# ASP.Net layered communication

Tags: asp.net, data-access-layer, loose-coupling, loose-typing

We're developing a layered web application. The specs:

- 3 layers, data layer, business layer,
  ui layer.
- Programmed in C#
- Data Layer uses the entity framework

Currently we plan on having the data layer return `IEnumerable<T>` to the business layer via linq 2 entities, and the business layer will return data to the ui layer.

Since the ui layer has no knowledge of the existance of the data layer, how would it handle a result of IEnumerable passed to it from the BLL, where T is defined in the data layer?

Are there any GOOD example out there on how to do this. Please note that I'm extremely new to factories / interfaces / abstraction to loosely couple layers.

I saw the question here [passing data in an ntier application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917457/passing-data-in-an-ntier-application) and it was recommended to have the entity layer shared amongst all layers... however I do not want the other layers to be able to query the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your data objects defined in a separate project, or at least a separate namespace, so the Display layer can have a reference to the objects, but not the DAL that has access to the db.

Comment: Since the Entity Framework automagically creates the DTO's and my entity data model is in my data layer, how would I go about having Visual Studio create these DTO's elsewhere?

Comment: I ended up using T4 to create the DTO's for me.